# Finding recurring pattern between two characters, selecting a specific part from each match (excluding recurring parts)

Tags: regex-group

I constructed this overly specific pattern:

```
(?:{)([\w\s]+),\s*([\w\s]+)?,\s*([\w\s]+),?\s*([\w\s]+)(?:})
```

To find from this piece of text..

```
{a1, b2, c3, d4} hello there {a1, b2, c3, d4}
```

The following matches and groups:

```
match1: {a1, b2, c3, d4}
  group1: a1
  group2: b2
  group3: c3
  group4: d4
match2: {a1, b2, c3, d4}
  group1: a1
  group2: b2
  group3: c3
  group4: d4
```

I've tried to simplify the pattern, but it doesn't yield the same result. Instead it only finds `d4`'s.

```
(?:{)(([\w\s]+)(?:,?\s*))+(?:})
```

```
match1: {a1, b2, c3, d4}
  group1: d4
  group2: d4
match2: {a1, b2, c3, d4}
  group1: d4
  group2: d4
```

I'm encountering this problem more often, and I repeatidly find myself creating far too specific patterns.

Comment: In the last pattern you are repeating a capture group, which will capture only the value of the last iteration in the group. If you are using .net or the python regex module you could use the captures property.

Comment: You could also for example capture the data inside the curly's in group 1, and then split the group 1 value on a comma. https://jsfiddle.net/7raxfb2e/